# Push Checked Object in new array Angular js

Tags: angularjs, arrays, html

I want to Push checked object into new array & also do sum / count of total price my angular / HTML code is :

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="daysheet in daysheets">

<div class="panel-heading">
    <h1 class="panel-title">{{daysheet.charge_client_name}}</h1>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form_{{daysheet.id}}">

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Rate</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th>Invoice</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="jobd in daysheet.job_details">
                    <td style="width: 70px">
                        <input type="text" name="qty[]" value="{{jobd.product_quantity}}" class="form-control ">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px">
                        <input type="text" value="{{jobd.job_product_rate}}" name="rate[]" class="form-control " disabled>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="{{jobd.job_product_total_rate}}" name="total[]" ng-model="total" class="form-control total_count">
                    </td>
                    <td> //checkbox when user checked show this object amount and push value in new array 
                        <input type="checkbox" name="send_in[]" class="invoice_s_{{daysheet.id}}"  ng-model="selectedjob">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="13">
                        <p class="pull-right "> Selected joblines Total <u>// select checkbox  amount(job_product_total_rate) / sum of all selected checkbox total amount(job_product_total_rate)  goes here</u>
                        </p>

                        <p class="pull-right "> Total Amount <u class="tot_amt">//total amount goes here</u>
                        </p>

                    </td>

                </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

and API Response is :

```
[  
  {  
  "id":"2",
  "charge_client_name":"Ridgeway Bank",
  "job_details":[  
     {  

        "job_id":"4",
        "product_quantity":"55",
        "job_product_rate":"120",
        "job_product_total_rate":"6600",
        "distance":"200"
     },
     {  
        "job_id":"2",            
        "product_quantity":"55",           
        "job_product_rate":"120",
        "job_product_total_rate":"6600",
        "distance":"12"
     }
  ]
 },
 {  
  "id":"1",
  "charge_client_name":"Woolworths Market",
  "job_details":[  
     {              
        "job_id":"1",
        "product_quantity":"1200",
        "job_product_rate":"1200",
        "job_product_total_rate":"1440000",
        "distance":"100"
      }
   ]
 }]
```

in which i want to show all amount / total amount of all object like all sum of { job_product_total_rate } and when we click / checked the checkbox push object value in new array .
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your example:
https://jsfiddle.net/e9ps7oa7/

You can use [checklist-model](https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model) to create lists with checkboxes.

`$scope.getTotalAmount` function is to calculate sum of properties in array
and you can find all checked *job_details* in `daysheet.selected` array

Comment: Thank u it worked that i want.......